# Allow WhatsApp calls in Silent / Do Not Disturb mode - Android 10

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, android-10, do-not-disturb

Has anyone come across a way to allow WhatsApp calls to ring & vibrate when a phone is set in Silent / DND mode on Android 10 (Device = Pixel 3A)?

The [starred contacts route](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9069335?hl=en-GB) seems to work for regular phone calls & SMSes only and does not seem to include WhatsApp calls in the exceptions list.

If anyone has come across a solution to this & is willing to share it, would be appreciated.

Regards,

Harsh